# Regex masking all phone numbers except a specific range

Tags: regex, perl, genesys

Not 100% if this is possible but I would like to convert any outbound call that does not match my DID range to a set phone number.

With our carrier in Australia if the ANI is not from their supplied range the call is blocked as part of new regulations.

What I am looking for is something like this.

if not +61 2 XXXX XXXX - +61 2 XXXX  XXXX  then send as +612XXXX XXXX

I apologise I have no true understanding of regex and do not know even where to begin.

I am starting to work on my knowledge of it though. please be kind. If anyone can point me to an "idiots guide" link I would be appreciative as I am just getting into this.

Comment: You demonstration/example/description leaves a lot to be desired. Is it fair to say you have data from one source of the form `+61 2 XXXX XXXX`, `+61 2 YYYY YYYY`, `+61 2 ZZZZ ZZZZ`. You also have a stream of numbers. For each numbers `+61 2 IIII IIII` from this stream, if it falls within the inclusive range `+61 2 XXXX XXXX` to `+61 2 YYYY YYYY`, return `+61 2 IIII IIII` else return `+61 2 ZZZZ ZZZZ`?

Comment: Could you clarify the question?  In what format are you trying to match the phone number?  As an integer or a formatted string?  What you're asking to do is trivial, you just need to define the problem.  That will determine if regex should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. It's just a  matter of how much work you want to do. I'm not quite sure what you want to mask and what you want to pass on unmutilated. A couple of particular examples would help. How many different formats, countries, and so on do you need to support?

With these problems, I tend to follow this approach:

1. Normalize the data. Make them all look the same. So, remove all non-digits, for example. `+61 2 XXXX XXXX` turns into `612XXXXXXXX`. In this step, you'd also fill in implicit information, like a local number that does not include the country code. [Number::Phone](https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::Phone) may be interesting, but, also note is was the largest distro on CPAN for awhile.
2. Now it should be easier to recognize the number and it's components (because if it isn't, you didn't do Step 1 right). Instead of a regex, you might use a parser. That is, get the country code, and then from that, decide what has to happen next. That's the sort of thing I have to do with ISBNs in [Business::ISBN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Business::ISBN), which have a group code then a publisher code (both of which are variable length.
3. Once you can recognize the number, it's easy to select a range. If it's in the range, you know what to replace.

Comment: The closes I have gotten is match expression of  ^(sip[s]?:|tel:)(\+61)73212345)(\d{2})(.*) and a format to of $1$2$3$4 but I seem to be able to get a match when verifying in regex101.com